# Alert Based on Else/If In

Tags: javascript, if-statement

very new to coding.  I am testing to see if I can make an alert display based on a variable.  I have the below code and I am trying to figure out why, in its current state, it is not displaying the "bye" alert.  Here is the code:

```
document.getElementById("square").onclick=square;
function square(){
    var test="a";
    if (test="v") {
        alert("hi");
    }
    else{
        alert("bye");
    }
}
```

Comment: `test="v"` Assignments are always true. What you want is [`==` or `===`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp).

Answer (score 1):

In your if statement, you need to write:

```
if (test === "v") {
    alert("hi");
}
```

The way you have it right now, `if (test="v")` sets the variable `test` to the value `v` before evaluating the `if` statement. This is basically the same as doing this:

```
function square() {
    test = "a";
    test = "v";
    if (test) {
        alert("hi");
    } else {
        alert("bye");
    }
}
```

Here, `if(test)` just asks if the variable `test` is not `null`, `undefined`, or an empty string `''`. Because your variable does have a value `"v"`, `if(test)` will always be true, so `alert('hi')` will always be run.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `=` which is an assignment operator.

Problem is in line

```
 if (test="v") {
```

instead of `=`, use

```
 if (test== "v") {
```

*OR*

```
 if (test==="v") {
```

The identity (`===`) operator behaves identically to the equality (`==`) operator except no type conversion is done, and the types must be the same to be considered equal.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `=` instead of `==` to compare variable test with value `v`.

The equal operator is for assignments: you use it to assign a value to a variable.
An assignment expression return the value you're assigning, so, in your case, `v`.

And since in javascript every non-empty string is coerced as `true`  boolean value, your if branch is executed.

You should have used the `==` or `===` operator instead.

---

The `==` operator coerced two values to the same type, and return `true` if they are equal. So, for example,

`2 == 1 + 1` => true

but also

`"2" == 1 + 1` => true

---

The `===` operator is for strict equality. It doesn't coerce values type, and only return `true` if they are equal both in type and value. So, for example,

`2 == 1 + 1` => true

but

`"2" == 1 + 1` => false

because you're comparing a string with a number

Answer (score 0):

To check a condition you should use `a == b` to check if value `a` is equal to value `b`
in your code you set the value of test variable to 'v'

Comment: Please, finish your question.

Comment: tanks @ManoloSalsas for your adivise ;)